# Summing same cell across hundreds of Excel workbooks

Tags: sum, external, excel

I have around 500 timecards. Each timecard is it's own file (.xls workbook). I need a total of cell K5 from all those workbooks.  This is a one time thing (every quarter) - I don't need the result to be updated if any of those 500+ timecards change.

It would be great if there was a function that took two parameters - 1) the name of the directory containing the Excel files; 2) the specific cell you want totaled.

After 3.5 hours of searching, the Excel forums haven't helped. I must be using bad keywords, as I can't believe Excel doesn't have such basic functionality.  (I did find some stuff if I had multiple worksheets in the same workbook - we would not be able to maintain all those time cards in the same file, and going through and opening all the workbooks at the same time would be very tedious - 500+ double-clicks.)

Thanks.

(Windows XP SP3; Microsoft Office Excel 2003)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some code that will prompt for a folder to be selected and then cycle all files in that folder for worksheet name *[Worksheetname = "Sheet1"]* and *[CELL = "K5"]* and sum the totals in cell K5.

Hopefully this will get you started. You will need to ensure all files have a valid 'Worksheetname' or insert a test.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ReadFilesinFolder()
'**Opens File Dialog and cycles all files for batch or just single file
Dim objFs As Object, objF As Object, objF1 As Object, objFc As Object
Dim strEndofPath As String, strFilePath As String, strFilename As String
Dim lngCount As Long, Worksheetname As String, CELL As String, objWB As Workbook, objWS As Worksheet
Dim dblTOTAL As Double

Worksheetname = "Sheet1"
CELL = "K5"


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        End
    End If

    For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        strEndofPath = InStrRev(.SelectedItems(lngCount), "\")
        strFilePath = Left(.SelectedItems(lngCount), strEndofPath)
        strFilename = Right(.SelectedItems(lngCount), Len(.SelectedItems(lngCount)) - strEndofPath)
    Next lngCount
End With

Set objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objF = objFs.GetFolder(strFilePath)

    'Batch Import
    Set objFc = objF.Files
    For Each objF1 In objFc
    DoEvents

        Set objWB = GetObject(objF1)
        Set objWS = objWB.Sheets(Worksheetname)
        dblTOTAL = dblTOTAL + objWS.Range(CELL).Value

        objWB.Close
        Set objWB = Nothing

    Next objF1
 msgbox dblTOTAL
End Sub
```

Comment: The file dialog doesn't let me select a directory, and it won't let me select multiple files.  When I select a single .xls file, I get a run-time error "type mismatch" on this line "Set objWB = GetObject(objF1)"  I haven't added a subroutine before. In the Visual Basic editor, I added the subroutine, then Run->Run Sub/Userform (I followed the instructions I found here to add/run a subroutine: http://www.ehow.com/how_6186281_use-subroutine-excel-visual-basic.html)

Comment: I don't know what "or insert a test" means in your instructions.  The .xls files have a "valid 'Worksheetname'" only if Excel did that automatically when the files were created. Thanks.

Comment: Try the code again, I forgot to close each workbook when finished. The code assumes all the data is on a worksheet named 'Sheet1'. Either change 'Sheet1' to what you need or if worksheet names are not consistent then you will need to add further logic to identify which sheet name the data from K5 is on.

Comment: Same result. Then I changed .AllowMultiSelect to True.  Now I can select multiple files, and I don't get the run time error (from selecting one file.) Nothing is changed in the worksheet I put the subroutine in - it's still all empty - no total.  In the code, I don't see where dblTOTAL is ever assigned to anything, and the procedure doesn't seem to have a return value type (if I called it in a Macro, and then assigned a cell to the return value). (I'm familiar with 'c' and Pascal, not QB.)

Comment: It isn't working. I added a watch to dblTOTAL and it says "out of context." (I did that as the variable doesn't ever appear to be assigned to anything, as I said in the above comment.)  Also I'm having to click "no" on every single file that gets opened - "do you want to save the changes."  How do I make that go away?  I get the same thing if I open one of the timecard .xls files, and then close it (without doing anything.)  Excel asks if I want to save the changes.  I guess Excel is changing something automatically.  How do I stop that?

Comment: I got it working (with your updated code, above).  THANKS.  I figured out from other sites: ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = dblTOTAL will put the value in my current workbook; objWB.Saved = True stops the dialogs from popping up asking me to save files.